# how do i get 1 of the data with all the same columns in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say we have some data;

```
id          1   2   3
price       5   5   7
old_price   5   5   8
```

I want it like this;

```
id          1    3
price       5    7
old_price   5    8
```

How its work in oracle?

Comment: You want the minimum ID per price and old_price?

Comment: It looks like you're transposed rows and columns to post your data? Anyway... what is the logic that gives your desired result - *why* should it show that output, and exclude ID 2? We can guess, but it would be better if you explained it clearly in the your question.

Comment: Actually i want to get 1 of the rows with the same 2 columns.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statement for your sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output for that sample data. The biggest issue is that your sample data has the headers in the first column of each row and no column headers so it is unclear why the answer would not be something like `SELECT column1, column2, column4 FROM your_table`.

Comment: PL/SQL is the programming language for procedure, functions etc. Sounds like your question only needs SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
 select min(id) as id, price, old_price from your_table_name group by price, old_price
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select the named columns:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column4
FROM   your_table
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (column1, column2, column3, column4) AS
SELECT 'id',        1, 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'price',     5, 5, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'old_price', 5, 5, 8 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | 1 | 3 |
| price | 5 | 7 |
| old_price | 5 | 8 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-FKPPWNA)